# Why is my accordion text overlapping the arrow?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jquery-ui widget called accordion to display two pieces of text to the user. As you can see in the screenshot the text is overlapping the arrow and I don't know why.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my HTML:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Test A' /}

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Alpha</h3>
    <div>
        Hi!
    </div>

    <h3>Beta</h3>
    <div>
        Lo!
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            clearStyle: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>#{get 'title' /}</title>
        <meta charset="${_response_encoding}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/main.css'}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@{'public/stylesheets/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'}" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ultra|Shanti" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        #{get 'moreStyles' /}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@{'/public/images/favicon.png'}">
        <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        #{get 'moreScripts' /}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="main">
                #{doLayout /}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Some trifling words.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I am having trouble changing the size of the header text. I tried this in my main.css but it doesn't work, only the font changes, not the size:

```
h3 {
    font-family: 'Ultra', Arial, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Comment: I'd hate to be that guy, but could you throw this into a JFiddle bro?

Comment: try adding some padding-left to h3

Comment: check the loading order of javascripts, I had headackes with a project o mine in rails 3 when if one jquery element is working then the second is not, and back, the second is working the first not.. so by playing with js files I realized that the loading order of js does matter. the proper order should be jquery 1.4.4,
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js  - and by the way, using the latest jquery made me problems also, I took the 1.4.4 now evertyhing works fine.

Comment: Here is a jfiddle (very nice site): http://jsfiddle.net/L4MEW/4/

Comment: where that arrow/text supposed to be?

Comment: @satur9nine, well this worked - `#accordion h3 { padding-left: 100px; }`

Comment: Nice, but why does it work when I write "#accordion h3" in the css, but doesn't work if I just write "h3"?

Comment: I guess it works because of the nature of cascading style sheets, something in jquery ui must clobber the regular h3 style. Janis, if you put your comment as an answer I can award you the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Janis Lankovskis answered this question in the comments. The solution was to do this in the CSS:

```
#accordion h3 { padding-left: 100px; }
```